# php array not showing up in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, arrays

I created an array of values from data in MySQL. I then try to print it in Javascript but unfortunately it is not showing up.
Database has two cols: `gurtej` and `singh`

```
<?php
require_once('config.php');
function readAttribute($connect){
    $resultArray=array();
    $sql="SELECT Attributename,Entityname FROM temp_data_attribute";
    $res=mysqli_query($connect,$sql);
    echo mysqli_num_rows($res);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($res)==0){
        return 0;
    }
    else{
        while($result=mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
            array_push($resultArray,$result[0]);
        }

        return $resultArray;
    }

}
?>
<html>
<body>
<script>
    var jArray= <?php
$resultArray=readAttribute($connect);
if($resultArray==0){
$resultArray=[];
}
echo json_encode($resultArray);?>;
    var counter=<?php echo count($resultArray);?>;
    document.write(jArray[0]);

</script>
<?php
print_r($resultArray);
?>
</body>
</html>
```

And when i try to print it in php using `print_r` this is the result.

> Array ( [0] => gurtej [1] => singh )

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The resulting JavaScript statement includes more than just the `var` and `array` as JSON:

```
var jArray = 2["gurtej","singh"];
```

The extra `2` comes from the `echo` within `readAttribute()` showing the number of rows:

```
function readAttribute($connect){
    $resultArray=array();
    $sql="SELECT Attributename,Entityname FROM temp_data_attribute";
    $res=mysqli_query($connect,$sql);
    echo mysqli_num_rows($res);
//  ^^^^
```

By following the number, the "array" changes meaning and is interpreted as a [bracket property accessor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors) with a [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator). The statement behaves the same as:

```
var jArray = (2).singh;
```

And, the number `2` doesn't (normally) have a property named `singh`. So, you get `undefined`, which can't have properties.

```
console.log(typeof jArray); // 'undefined'
console.log(jArray[0]);     // TypeError
```

---

To remove the `2`, you'll want to remove or comment out the additional `echo`:

```
function readAttribute($connect){
    $resultArray=array();
    $sql="SELECT Attributename,Entityname FROM temp_data_attribute";
    $res=mysqli_query($connect,$sql);
    // echo mysqli_num_rows($res);
    // ...
}
```

```
var jArray = ["gurtej","singh"];

console.log(typeof jArray); // "object"
console.log(jArray[0]);     // "gurtej"
```

Comment: Thank you buddy !! you saved my life :D

Answer (score 0):

Let's clean up that function a bit and we'll fix the problem too

```
function readAttribute($connect){
    $resultArray = array();
    $sql="SELECT Attributename,Entityname FROM temp_data_attribute";
    $res=mysqli_query($connect,$sql);
    //echo mysqli_num_rows($res);

    while($result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){
        $resultArray[] = $result;
    }

    return $resultArray;
}
```

Your problem is that you were using `$result[0]`, but that just pushes the first column. And if you're going to `json_encode` this, I would avoid using `fetch_array()` (without an argument) because it returns both a numeric AND associative key value for each column (which will inflate your data set of rows)

Comment: please help me :'(

Answer (score 0):

Lets clean up the code:

```
<html>
<body>
<!-- container to hold data -->
<div id='container'></div>
<script>
   <?php 
      //--- get the results from the database
      $resultArray=readAttribute($connect);
      //--- convert if necessary
      if($resultArray==0){
         $resultArray=[];
      }
   ?>;
   //--- place results into JavaScript array
   var jArray= <?php echo json_encode($resultArray);?>;
   //--- show the raw array
   document.getElementById('container').innerHTML = jArray[0];
</script>
<?php
print_r($resultArray);
?>
</body>
</html>
```